# Fullcalendar+moment.js give moment.defineLocale deprecation warning

Tags: fullcalendar, momentjs

I'm using latest fullcalendar (3.1.0) and moment.js, and got a warning in console:

"*Deprecation warning: use moment.updateLocale(localeName, config) to change an existing locale. moment.defineLocale(localeName, config) should only be used for creating a new locale See http://momentjs.com/guides/#/warnings/define-locale/ for more info.*".

Just after initialization:

```
moment.locale('ru');
moment.tz.setDefault('Europe/Moscow');
...
$('#schedule').fullCalendar({
    lang: 'ru',
    ...
});
```

But I can't find call to `defineLocale` anywhere.
Other pages that also using moment.js is ok.
Where is the problem?
Thank you.

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/3076) a similar issue, is it your case?

Comment: Yes, seems like a bug-feature of fullcalendar. Thank you.